Scaling different parts of a model differently
recently I have been trying to print models of steel buildings using just I beams. I start by downloading a file of one and then scale them way down to fit the print bed. But when I scale them down to a printable size (anywhere from 1 to.1 percent of the original model) a lot of the walls are too skinny to show up after slicing. I want to be able to thicken the web and flanges without changing the length of the beam. What is a good way to accomplish this? I thought I could scale the beams along the axis that thicken the web(center) and the axis to make the top and bottom I thicker but I couldn't find a way to do this efficiently after googling for some time. Is there a good way to be able to select multiple parts and scale them on 2 axes, then select other beams to use different axes? Or am I going about it the wrong way? I am using bamboo studio as a slicer and trying to print on the x1 carbon.

What you can't can't be done by scaling the object itself. You need to go into edit mode and manipulate the faces themselves to achieve that. If you select one or more faces in edit mode, and press alt+S, you can move them along the normal, i.e. it would thicken the part.
Can you show a picture of the beam? Depending on what detail they have you might be better off creating an actual object that can adjusted quickly from scratch than manipulating an existing one
